# Difference between "Ode to" and "Ode on"?

Tags: poetry, terminology

We sometimes see **Ode to** and sometimes **Ode on**.

Do these both mean **a poem written about something?**

I am a new literature student.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An ode is not just any poem, but specifically a:

> lyric poem, serious in subject, elevated in style, and elaborate in its stanzaic structure.
>
> <sub>M. H. Abrams (1957). *A Glossary of Literary Terms*, p. 116. New York: Holt, Rinehart and Winston.</sub>

where a lyric poem is a:

> nonnarrative poem presenting a single speaker who expresses a state of mind or a process of thought and feeling.
>
> <sub>Abrams, p. 89</sub>

The ode originated with the ancient Greeks, notably [Pindar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pindar) and [Sappho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sappho). Lyric poems are so-called because they were originally sung and accompanied on a [lyre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyre).

In English poetry, if an ode is written as if speaking *to* the subject (addressing it in the second person), then it would be an “ode to”. If an ode is written *about* the subject (referring to it in the third person) then it would be an “ode on”.

Taking examples from the works of [John Keats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Keats), ‘[Ode to a Nightingale](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44479/ode-to-a-nightingale)’ is addressed to a nightingale:

> Thou wast not born for death, immortal Bird!
>         No hungry generations tread thee down;

Whereas ‘[Ode on Melancholy](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44478/ode-on-melancholy)’ is addressed to someone suffering from melancholy, not to melancholy itself, which is referred to in the third person:

> Ay, in the very temple of Delight
>         Veil’d Melancholy has her sovran shrine,

But this is not a hard-and-fast rule! ‘[Ode on a Grecian Urn](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44477/ode-on-a-grecian-urn)’ is addressed to the urn but titled with “on”. Perhaps Keats chose this form of title because the urn is not the only addressee: parts of the poem are addressed instead to the figures depicted on the urn.